# Storyboard: Views with navigation controller before tabbar issue

Tags: ios, window, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, flip

I have a little problem related to implementing a tabBar with navigation controllers, when I have two views before the tabBar controller, which also uses a navigation controller.
This is my setup:
Have my separate navigation controller(with two view controllers) be the rootViewController of your window until the user move to tabBar view. Then change it to be the UITabBarController (which does not include the previous view controllers). I do this in my second controller file.

When I tried to flip some view controller which is on tabBar, its showing previous controller view in background while flipping.